# Smart way of resizing images in PHP

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I was wondering if someone can help me with an image resize function written in PHP but one wich has to resize an image, but in a manner like PHPThumb does. So, if I set the width and height of the new image, the function must fit the uploaded image (and mantain aspect ratio) in the new width and height.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, searching would definitely help. See 'Related'

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this a couple years ago and it does exactly what you're looking for.  Keep in mind this only calculates the width and height, you must call Imagick yourself to actually apply these calculations.

```
/**
* ImageIntelligentResize()
* 
* @global Intelligently resizes images using a providid max width and height
* @param mixed $imagePath
* @param mixed $maxWidth
* @param mixed $maxHeight
* @param mixed $alwaysUpscale
* @return
*/
function ImageIntelligentResize( $imagePath, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $alwaysUpscale )
{
    // garbage in, garbage out
    if ( IsNullOrEmpty($imagePath) || !is_file($imagePath) || IsNullOrEmpty($maxWidth) || IsNullOrEmpty($maxHeight) )
    {
        return array("width"=>"", "height"=>"");
    }

    // if our thumbnail size is too big, adjust it via HTML
    $size = getimagesize($imagePath);
    $origWidth = $size[0];
    $origHeight = $size[1];

    // Check if the image we're grabbing is larger than the max width or height or if we always want it resized
    if ( $alwaysUpscale || $origWidth > $maxWidth || $origHeight > $maxHeight )
    {   
        // it is so let's resize the image intelligently
        // check if our image is landscape or portrait
        if ( $origWidth > $origHeight )
        {
            // target image is landscape/wide (ex: 4x3)
            $newWidth = $maxWidth;
            $ratio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
            $newHeight = floor($origHeight * $ratio);
            // make sure the image wasn't heigher than expected
            if ($newHeight > $maxHeight)
            {
                // it is so limit by the height
                $newHeight = $maxHeight;
                $ratio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;
                $newWidth = floor($origWidth * $ratio);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // target image is portrait/tall (ex: 3x4)
            $newHeight = $maxHeight;
            $ratio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;
            $newWidth = floor($origWidth * $ratio);
            // make sure the image wasn't wider than expected
            if ($newWidth > $maxWidth)
            {
                // it is so limit by the width
                $newWidth = $maxWidth;
                $ratio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
                $newHeight = floor($origHeight * $ratio);
            }
        }
    }
    // it's not, so just use the current height and width
    else
    {
        $newWidth = $origWidth;
        $newHeight = $origHeight;
    }   

    return array("width"=>$newWidth, "height"=>$newHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When i started learning OOP, i wroted [this image class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5340.html) to practice myself.

It uses GD, ans surely can be improved, hope it helps.

**edit**: after 2 downvotes for a issue where i dont have any control, i put the class on pastie.

[The class](http://pastie.org/743960)

[The Example](http://pastie.org/743963)

Remember, the class works fine, but it was a practice in order to learn basics OOP.

I hope this will be ok, you lazy users ;)

*at Christmas we are all better people*

Comment: LOL i cant believe, im not the one who require you to login, that's how phpclasses.org works, not my fault.

didnt you never seen that site?

Comment: and may i ask why it has a so bad reputation?

Comment: hahahah thanks, but now im pretty curious to know why phpclasses sucks.. is use just a couple of time, but didnt look that bad ;) i'll google for it!

Comment: Just FYI: PHPClasses site doesn't require users to login by itself. It's an option of authors to require the users to be logged to download. That's explained in the contribution rules. Most authors keep that requirement because it's good for them. The site only keeps track of who downloaded each package if the users are logged. That tracking is used to notify users that previously downloaded a package when it's updated. There are other benefits often misunderstood by complainers. The site is the largest repository of PHP components due to those benefits: over 5000 from more than 3000 authors.

Comment: @mlemos: you could be right, but I swear i never set that option, probably is a 'hidde' or 'default checked' option ;)

Comment: @DaNieL, very likely you left it in the default as most authors do, which is you decide on a file by file basis. Anyway, you should not feel guilty about that because the for most authors the default is beneficial to them as it increases your chances of getting more feedback from your users after each update.

Comment: youre probably right ;) I do not feel guilty, but i admit that register in order to see a file i put in my question can be nasty

Comment: It depennds on whether you are providing a solution that probably nobody is providing, which may not be the case. It also depends on the reason why you submitted the package to PHPClasses. If you want to increase the chances that a large number of people get your code and keep coming back to get updated versions of the code or when you post blog articles in the site about, the login requirement helps you on that purpose. However, you never updated your package nor wrote any article about it. It's never too late though.

Comment: i love it mate, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

- the resize then crop approach: compute the aspect ratio of the source image and use it as a constraint to create an intermediate image which is going to be larger than the destination image (either in width or height) - finally crop the intermediate image to the destination dimensions.
- use [seam carving](http://www.seamcarving.com/)! also called ["liquid rescale" in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale) (see also [there](http://valokuva.org/?p=99))

If you can rely on [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) being installed on your server, it offers many more features than GD.

Answer (score 2):

from my understanding, OP's question is more about calculating new dimensions, rather than resizing

@Psyche, this is actually a simple arithmetic issue. Suppose you have an 640x480 image and want to show it in a 200x200 "box".

```
$sw = 640; $sh = 480;
$dw = 200; $dh = 200;
```

find out the aspect ratio of the box, compare it with that of original and calculate either width of height for the new image

```
$sr = $sw / $sh;
$dr = $dw / $dh;
if($sr > $dr)
    $dh = round($dw / $sr);
else
    $dw = round($dh * $sr);
```

this gives you 200x150 and this is the size to which you need to scale the original image

Answer (score 0):

I would use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). Both great libraries to do that and more.

Answer (score 0):

at least this is small (and useful): http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php