# How to resize an image as follows?

Tags: php, gd

I need to resize an image to a defined width and height but crop the bottom to the height if it is larger or add blank space to the bottom if it is smaller. How to accomplish that with the help of PHP's GD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart way of resizing images in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906899/smart-way-of-resizing-images-in-php)

Comment: Does that do the centring? If so, I do not need it; just crop the bottom or add blank space to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I maid a function for this: [PHP/GD Imagestyle](https://github.com/lyrisias/PHP-GD-Imagestyle)
You can create thumbnails exactly as you described with the following:

```
$thumb = imagestyle($image,'autosize:100 100');
```

But also if you need something more complicated you can use:

```
// resize 200 0 means width=200 height=auto
$thumb = imagestyle($image,'resize:200 0; crop:200 200;');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpThumb library.
Take a look  https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage