# imagecopyresampled Resize to max-width OR height, but keep ratio

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I have the following code that I use to resize some images on my server to a smaller size:

```
// get the ratio of the original image
list($orgwidth, $orgheight) = getimagesize($originalImageDir);
// create a thumb and source image to be resized
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImageDir);
// resize
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, round($height / $ratio), $height, $orgwidth, $thumbheight);
// save new thumb with quality 75
imagejpeg($thumb, $path, 75);
```

I am running into the following problem: I give my function a height and width of 300 and 200 respectively. Now, the original images are not that ratio, so I would like to be able to resize the original to a maximum width of 200 or a max height of 300; whichever one is the larger value.

So for example, if I have a 1200h x 1000w image, I want to resize it to a height of 240px and 200px, because in this case 200px was my maximum allowed width. And if I had an image that is 480h x 300w my new image would be resized to 300px height and 187px width because 300px is my maximum height and this brings me below the maximum allowed width.

Hope I am making sense. Anyway, if any php and math wizards have something cooked up, please do share :)

Thanks!

Comment: There have to be hundreds of duplicates of this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smart way of resizing images in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906899/smart-way-of-resizing-images-in-php)

Comment: calculate the aspect ratio of original image and then check to see if the width/height of final image which you need comes under that aspect ratio or not.  If not you might need to change your width and height of final image.  But if you dont want to change the widht/height of your final image, it might be distorted or blurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not look at something like http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Transform/ that has various drivers for different image libraries and has just the functionality you are looking for?